# Strange behaviour of JPA version using Orika for class mapping. Children version is incremented, but shouldn't

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, orika

In my database model each entity has version field.
I have three simple entities (client, debt, payment) with @OneToMany realtions. Client has many debts. Debt has many payments. 
I'm also using Orika for class mapping (dto -> entity and entity -> dto).

I have 2 test cases:

1. I have fully filled and persisted ClientEntity. Then I change a
   few times only one property in ClientEntity and save after each change. On the end of the test case
   version of ClientEntity is incremented. Version of children entities
   is 0 (because they are not changed).
2. When I do same test case, but using ClientDto with Orika mapping,
   on the end of test case I see that not only Client version is
   incremented, but also child entity which wasn't changed.

I can not understand this behaviour and I don't know why it happens.
I created simple project with test written where it's easy to recognize what is wrong, please see: https://github.com/Kondziqq/jpa-versioning-problem.git.

The most important code parts:

ClientEntity:

```
// necessary annotations
public class ClientEntity extends BaseEntity {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "CLIENT_SEQUENCE", name = "CLIENT_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CLIENT_SEQUENCE")
private Long id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private String language;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
private Set<DebtEntity> debts;
}
```

DebtEntity:

```
// necessary annotations
public class DebtEntity extends BaseEntity {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "DEBT_SEQUENCE", name = "DEBT_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DEBT_SEQUENCE")
private Long id;

private BigDecimal amount;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "debt_id")
private Set<PaymentEntity> payments;
}
```

BaseEntity:

```
// necessary annotations
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

@Version
private Integer version;

@CreatedDate
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date creationDate;

@LastModifiedDate
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastModificationDate;
}
```

Orika converter:

```
@Component
@Getter
public class Converter {

private MapperFacade mapper;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    var mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
    registerMappings(mapperFactory);
    mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
}

private void registerMappings(DefaultMapperFactory mapperFactory) {

    mapperFactory.classMap(BaseDto.class, BaseEntity.class).byDefault().register();
    mapperFactory.classMap(Client.class, ClientEntity.class).byDefault().register();
    mapperFactory.classMap(Debt.class, DebtEntity.class).byDefault().register();
    mapperFactory.classMap(Payment.class, PaymentEntity.class).byDefault().register();

    mapperFactory.classMap(BaseEntity.class, BaseDto.class).byDefault().register();
    mapperFactory.classMap(ClientEntity.class, Client.class).byDefault().register();
    mapperFactory.classMap(DebtEntity.class, Debt.class).byDefault().register();
    mapperFactory.classMap(PaymentEntity.class, Payment.class).byDefault().register();
}
}
```

ClientDao:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ClientDao implements ClientPersistence {

private final ClientRepository clientRepository;

private final Converter converter;

@Override
public long save(Client client) {

    var clientEntity = converter.getMapper().map(client, ClientEntity.class);
    return clientRepository.save(clientEntity).getId();
}

@Override
public Client getClientById(long id) {

    var client = clientRepository.getOne(id);
    return converter.getMapper().map(client, Client.class);
}
}
```

ClientDaoTest:

```
// this test fails
@Test
public void shouldNotIncrementChildVersionAfterParentDtoSaved() {

    // given
    var client = Client.builder()
            .firstName("John")
            .lastName("Smith")
            .language("pl")
            .debts(Set.of(
                    Debt.builder()
                            .amount(BigDecimal.valueOf(25000))
                            .payments(Set.of(Payment.builder().amount(BigDecimal.valueOf(2500)).date(Date.from(Instant.now())).build()))
                            .build()))
            .build();

    // when
    long id = clientDao.save(client);
    var clientCopy1 = clientDao.getClientById(id);

    clientCopy1.setLanguage("en");
    id = clientDao.save(clientCopy1);
    var clientCopy2 = clientDao.getClientById(id);

    clientCopy2.setLanguage("en");
    id = clientDao.save(clientCopy2);
    var clientCopy3 = clientDao.getClientById(id);

    // then
    assertEquals(3, clientCopy3.getVersion());
    assertEquals(0, clientCopy3.getDebts().iterator().next().getVersion());
}

// this test passes
@Test
public void shouldNotIncrementChildVersionAfterParentEntitySaved() {

    // given
    var clientEntity = ClientEntity.builder()
            .firstName("John")
            .lastName("Smith")
            .language("pl")
            .debts(Set.of(
                    DebtEntity.builder()
                            .amount(BigDecimal.valueOf(25000))
                            .payments(Set.of(PaymentEntity.builder().amount(BigDecimal.valueOf(2500)).date(Date.from(Instant.now())).build()))
                            .build()))
            .build();

    // when
    var clientEntityCopy = clientRepository.save(clientEntity);

    clientEntityCopy.setLanguage("en");
    clientEntityCopy = clientRepository.save(clientEntityCopy);

    clientEntityCopy.setLanguage("ru");
    clientEntityCopy = clientRepository.save(clientEntityCopy);

    // then
    assertEquals(2, clientEntityCopy.getVersion());
    assertEquals(0, clientEntityCopy.getDebts().iterator().next().getVersion());
}
```

**EDIT**

I finally found workaround for this problem. I changed unidirectional @OneToMany relation with @JoinColumn into bidirectional @OneToMany .
But I still have no idea why it doesn't work with unidirectional @OneToMany.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a primitive type for `BaseDto.version` which has a default value of 0. So if you map that object, 0 is initialized for the version. If you create the entity directly, null will be initialized for `BaseEntity.version` and Hibernate will give it the first value which I suppose is 1.

Comment: I changed it to Integer and unfortunately still doesn't work.
What's interesting when I don't fill last @OneToMany collection (payments) it works properly.

Comment: You can switch to using property accessors on your entities i.e. put the JPA annotations on the getters instead of on the fields. Then you can put a breakpoint in your setter and see why the version field is set and to which value. I think this should get you going.

Comment: I tried it, but in this case JPA iterates thru all setters and set same values. I think that the problem may be highly connected with nested @OneToMany relationship. As I said when I leave payments empty the problem doesn't occur. 
I have even tried to write my own mapper without Orika, but result is same.

Comment: I finally found workaround for this problem. I changed unidirectional OneToMany relation with JoinColumn into bidirectional OneToMany . But I still have no idea why it doesn't work with unidirectional OneToMany.